# Compare Strings in Do While Loop Java

Tags: java, loops, selenium, while-loop, do-while

I am learning Selenium in Java. I want to compare 2 strings in do while loop, I want loop to keep running unless my 2 strings value has been equal, when value is equal then loop should stop. 
Now I show you my code & tell you what I want to do with this code. 
it will open `https://www.facebook.com` , on Facebook homepage, class name of "First Name" field is "inputtext _58mg _5dba _2ph-". So I created a string variable `cname1` that will store class value of current focused element in loop, and `cname2` variable has value "inputtext _58mg _5dba _2ph-" , then I compare these 2 in do while loop, and loop should stop when `cname1` & `cname2` are equal. 
But it is not working, it stops in password field of Facebook instead of running until First Name field. Thanks

```
public class HelloWorldTest {
private static String cname1;
private static String cname2;

public static void main(String[] args) {

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/"); 
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).click(); 

do {
     driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
     WebElement element = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
     String cname1 = element.getAttribute("class");
     String cname2 = "inputtext _58mg _5dba _2ph-";
     System.out.println(cname1);
     System.out.println(cname2);
    }
    while ( cname1 != cname2 );
}

private void sendKeys(Keys enter) {}

}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I touched Java, but I believe Strings are treated like objects without boxing, so you cannot do a comparison literally on the variable name. You will need to use a compare function. See the linked question above by @engineer.
...while(!cname1.equals(cname2))...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this :

```
while ( !cname2.equals(cname1) );
```

Comment: Thanks, after changing i see this error   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at learningMaven.HelloWorldTest.main(HelloWorldTest.java:28)

Comment: i am using same code as given above

Comment: What's on line 28 of HelloWorldText.java? It's probably a null variable. I would speculate that cname1 is null.

Comment: this is line 28          while ( cname1 != cname2 );

Comment: in eclipse, my output is       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at learningMaven.HelloWorldTest.main(HelloWorldTest.java:28)
inputtext
inputtext _58mg _5dba _2ph-

Comment: Ah, You have defined cname1 and 2 twice, so they are null. You never actually update them.

Comment: what should i do now? do they not get any value in do-while loop? cname1 gets value from class name of facebook page fields and cname2 already have "inputtext _58mg _5dba _2ph-"

Comment: To be a bit more clear, the local variables `cname1` and `cname2` declared inside your loop body are *different variables* than the class variables of the same names.  You never initialize the class variables, so they have their default value, `null`.  The `while` condition is outside the loop body, so there `cname1` and `cname2` refer to the class variables.One way to fix this would be to avoid declaring new, local variables inside the loop body -- just remove the `String` before their names in the loop body to change the declarations into ordinary assignments.

Comment: You have declared cname1 & cname2 twice. Firstly, at the start of your class, and secondly inside your do loop. Remove the 'String' word before cname1 and cname2 inside your loop. This will stop new variables being created :).

Comment: @John Bollinger, Good answer!

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks a LOT

Comment: you really helped me and solved my problem instead of Marking as duplicate ;) Thanks again